# Why does clock offset error in the host keeps occurring again and again : cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have stopped the ntpd and restarted it again. Have done a ntpdate pool.ntp.org. the error went once and the hosts were healthy but after sometime again got a clock offset error.

Also I observed that after doing a ntpdate the web interface of cloudera stopped working. It says potential mismatch configuration fix and restart hue.

I have the cloudera quick start vm with centos setup on VMware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check if /etc/ntp.conf file is the same across all nodes/masters
- restart ntp
- add deamon with chkconfig and set it to on

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by restarting the NTP service which syncronizes the time with a central source.
You can do this by logging in as root from the commandline and running **service ntpd restart**.
After about a minute the error in CM shoud go away.

Host Terminal

> sudo su
>
> service ntpd restart

Answer (score 0):

Clock offset Error occur on Cloudera Manager if host\node's NTP service could not located or did not respond to a request for the clock offset.

Solution:

1)Identify NTP Server IP or Get details of NTP Server IP for your hadoop Cluster

2)On your Hadoop Cluster Nodes Edit-> `/etc/ntp.conf`

3)Add entries in ntp.conf

```
  server [NTP Server IP]
  server  xxx.xx.xx.x
```

4)Restart Services.Execute

```
 Service ntpd restart
```

5) Restart Cluster From Cloudera Manager

Note: If Problem Still Persist .Reboot you Hadoop Nodes & Check Process.

Answer (score 0):

Check $ cat /etc/ntp.conf make sure configuration file is same as others (nodes)

```
$ systemctl restart ntpd
$ ntpdc -np
$ ntpdate -u 0.centos.pool.ntp.org
$ hwclock --systohc
$ systemctl restart cloudera-scm-agent
```

After that wait a few seconds to let it auto configure.

Comment: what is ntpdate -u 0.centos.pool.ntp.org and how you get  0.centos.pool.ntp.org

Comment: it's update the clock system for CentOS, you can google it.